# Make component react to data change in state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following  layout of my vue app:

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Progress />
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import Progress from "@/components/Progress";

export default {
  components: {
    Footer,
    Progress,
  },
};
</script>
```

Code snippet for progress bar:

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="columns is-mobile pt-6" v-show="progressBar()">
      <div class="column is-three-fifths is-offset-one-fifth">
        <progress
          class="progress is-success"
          :value="(progress.count / 9) * 100"
          max="100"
          >{{ (progress.count / 9) * 100 }} %</progress
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Progress",
  methods: {
    progressBar() {
      console.log(this.progress.status);
      if (this.progress.status == false) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  computed: mapGetters({
    progress: "getProgressBar",
  }),
};
</script>
```

And vuex store for the progressbar.

**src/store/modules/ProgressBar.js**

```js
const state = {
  count: 1,
  status: false,  
};

const getters = {
  getProgressBar: state => state,
};

const actions = {
};

const mutations = {
  setProgressBar(state, value) {
    state.status = value;
  },
  progressIncrease(state) {
    state.status = state.status + 1;
    console.log(state.status);
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

And my route component **Basics.vue** which loads from the route `/basic`;

```js
<template>
  /* code for form layout goes here*/
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Basics",
  methods: {
    toNetworks() {
      this.$router.push({ name: "Location" });
      this.$store.commit("progressIncrease");
    },
    /* other codes to handel input */
  },
  created(){
    this.$store.commit("setProgressBar", true);
  }
};
</script>
```

With the above code I'm trying to increment the variable `count` in the state as per the form step increases and show the progress bar according to the calculation.

The states are set correctly and I can increment it with the commit. But the progresses bar component is not reacting to the updated data in the state.

I know that `mapGetter` method is called only once when the `<Progress/>` component is loaded in the `App.vue` component.

Is there any method/way to make the `<Progress/>` react to changes on the data in the state that are made from router component ?

Comment: I suggest you to use 2 getters - one to get the count and another to get the status.

Comment: Isn't `state.count = state.count + 1` in here?

`progressIncrease(state) {state.status = state.status + 1;console.log(state.status);}`

Answer (score 0):

In your progressIncrease mutation, you are increasing the wrong state (status - which is a boolean). You will need two getters. Also, I take it your getter should return the status and the count state.  You should have

```js
const mutations = {
  progressIncrease(state) {
    state.count = state.count + 1;
  }
};

const getters = {
  count: state => {
    return state.count;
  },
  status: state => {
    return state.status;
  }
}
```

In the component, you can use mapGetters as follows

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'count',
    'status',
  ])
}
```

You can replace `this.progress.status` with "this.status" and "this.progress.count" with "this.count". You can also use aliases if you please. You can see more about getters [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

The best practice, though, is to use mapState since you are returning the state and not altering it as in the vue docs example linked above.

That will become

```js
 computed: mapState({
    count: state => state.count,
    status: state => state.status,
 })
```

You can now call the states as `this.count` and `this.status`. Again, you can use an alias if you please. You can find out more about mapState [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)